# How do I get my phone to ring using Linphone and MagicJack?

Tags: voip, sip, telephony, phone

I have a VOIP number setup with Linphone and IPKall. I am using my old [magicJack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagicJack) to connect my handset. The handset works for voice input and output, but when I receive a call, it only rings in the handset speaker, so I have to set the output device to external speakers in order to hear an incoming call. Does anyone know how I can make my handset ring like a normal phone?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the cheapo FXO modem cards based on a TigerJet chip. Simple answer is no. Linphone or Skype or what ever you want would have to be modified to make the device understand rings and tones.

There has been some work on this. In any modern day Debian distro Ubuntu, Knoppix, Sidux or Simular) I know out of the box you can plug this in and it should come up as another audio device.

You should be able to in Linphone I use Skype and some other SIP software phone! I am able to configure the mic and speaker to use the device. I am guessing you already know that you can use it as a glorified sound card turning your phone into a earpeace and mic. (Handy for freeing yourself form your computer with Skype, Google voice/hangout and cordless.

These links below are old, but show promise in developing something that works. My hope is that possibly since digium played with the tigerjet that maybe there is a way to change the device to work with the usb fxs driver. If someone knows how or where to edit this, maybe, just maybe, it can become a fxs usable by asterisk pbx.

The fact that digium commented May 2002 that they looked at them for the S100U USB FXS might just be the little bit required to make use of these old 06e6 devices.

http://www.marko.net/asterisk/archives/0205/0195.html

http://web.archive.org/web/20040105044757/

http://www.marko.net/asterisk/archives/0205/0195.html

```
# lsusb
ID 06e6:c200 Tiger Jet Network, Inc. Internet Phone
ID 06e6:831c Tiger Jet Network, Inc.
```

A fellow put some effort in to trying to make it work: http://www.earth.li/~noodles/hardware-usbfxs.html

There is also a open project that needs some support. Looks like something that will make voip even cheaper and better!

http://openusbfxs.wordpress.com